# QtVLC plugins not found

Tags: qt, plugins, vlc

I'm using QtVLC (on a `Mac Os 10.8`) from [Git VLC](http://git.videolan.org/) which is in

> VLC/doc/libvlc/QtPlayer

and I compile with Qt. Unfortunately, it immediately throw this error :

> [0x101f2bfe0] main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.

I've tried to export vlc path using this :

```
export VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins/
```

and link by copying plugins near my QtVlc App but none of those works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember if VLC_PLUGIN_PATH is working, but this is OSX, so your environment variables from .profile are not used for graphical applications. (see [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x))

[EDITED]
Now, about the plugins folder: it should be put/linked relatively to the folder that contains your libvlc.dylib.
If libvlc.dylib is in somepath/lib/, your plugins are expected to be found in somepath/plugins.

Comment: To add to this, I'm pretty sure you only put the path up to the plugins folder. For example, if you plugins are in /my_folder/plugins, then set VLC_PLUGIN_PATH to /my_folder/.